# ReactJs - Merge state from Parent to Son in a hereditariness structure

Tags: reactjs

Im trying to use some Object Pattern in React Components because the usual Component->child structure require often a code rewriting.

```
class SuperComponentEveryOneWillLove extends React.component
{
   constructor(props){
      this.state = { master_state_all_will_use : 0 }
      this.commonFunction = this.commonFunction.bind(this);
      this.getMasterState = this.getMasterState.bind(this);
   }

   commonFunction() { return do_something; }
   getMasterState() { return this.state.master_state_all_will_use }
}

class PoorSon extends SuperComponentEveryOneWillLove
{
   constructor(props){
      this.state = { for_me_only : 0 }
   }

   render() {
       <span>  
           { this.state.master_state_all_will_use } //DOESN'T WORKS
           { this.getMasterState() } //DOESN'T WORKS
           { this.state.for_me_only } //WORKS
           { this.commonFunction() } //WORKS
       </span>
    }
}
```

I need to access Parent state and local state.
React allow function super calling but not merging state. I've tried on google to look for some "super" or "parent" keyword to access parent state but it seems it doesn't exists.
At runtime, Son component has no scope of Father's state.

Is this possibile?

Comment: Why do not pass `state/callbacks` as `props` to child?

Comment: Because in this structure, you never use SuperComponentEveryOneWillLove directly. You always refer to PoorSon, like every Object Oriented Language. SuperComponent is more like an AbstractClass.

Comment: JavaScript (and consequently React) is not an Object Oriented Language, so you can't expect to use it in the same way. The developers of React "recommend using composition instead of inheritance to reuse code between components." - https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it is what are you looking for, but it's close to it:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = { isParentState: true };
    // needed for getting access to parent state
    this.getMasterState = this.getMasterState.bind(this)
  }

  getMasterState(){
    return this.state;
  }
}

class Enhancer extends Parent {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    // get parent state via super keyword
    const parentState = super.getMasterState();
    this.state = {
      isChildState: true,
      ...parentState
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
      Merged state: { JSON.stringify(this.state)}
    </div>
  }
}
```

[`Worked example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/112416/).

Hope it helps

Comment: This is not a valid Higher-order component. 
"Concretely, a higher-order component is a function that takes a component and returns a new component." https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html

Also, inheritance is not the correct answer for this problem. Inheritance should almost never be used with React. The root of the problem (as I see it) is changing from an OO mindset. Am I crazy?

Comment: @Galupuf it can be done without HOC (HOC removed). About inheritance it depends on a logic. For sure there are a lot of cases where you can use HOCz or callbacks. Probably the OO problem it's better to fix with inheritance instead.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure it's possible, but you DO NOT want to do this.

Anything you are trying to do with inheritance can be done with composition.

In you case, your "parent component" will pass any information the children may need as props

```
class Parent extends React.component
{
  constructor(props){
    this.state = { parentState : 0 }
    this.parentFunction= this.commonFunction.bind(this);
  }

  parentFunction() { console.log("parentFunction()"); }

  render() {
    return (
      <Child 
        parentFunction={parentFuction} 
        parentState={this.parentState} 
      />
    )
  }
}
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html

**EDIT**

In React, inheritance is almost NEVER the answer.

Now if you're looking for a a way to reuse method logic, why not abstract the method to a helper file?

If that still doesn't work, perhaps a Higher Order Component (HOC) will do the trick.

Here's an example of a simple HOC:

```
const withCommonFunction = (WrappedComponent) => {
  return class extends React.Component {
    commonFunction() {
      console.log("I'm a common function that is needed in many components!");
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <WrappedComponent commonFunction={this.props.commonFunction} />
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Then you wrap whichever component you want to have the same logic with the HOC.

```
const Child = withCommenFunction(Child);
```

This is typically used to help reuse logic that would otherwise be implemented the same in different components

Comment: I think I miss something because TheReason ask me the same.
I can't use Render and Props pattern because SuperComponent will be extended by more than one ChildComponent. In the code, you never refer to ParentComponent directly. You will always user <PoorSon />. ParentComponent is like an AbstractClass that allow every Son to use some common method I don't want to rewrite in every Child.

With Your solution (that is the normale React pattern) I eventually need a big Switch that return a specific SonComponent.

Comment: In that case, what you want it a higher order component